BERTopic partial_fit placeholder cluster representation
I have approximately 2M text documents, each small, and want to cluster them.  (This will grow to about 500M eventually.)  While I am open to suggestions, I am currently using on-line techniques with the Python3 package BERTopic.  After using partial_fit on 140 chunks of 15k documents each I am left with a call to topic_model.get_topic_info() that returns unfinished cluster representations.  That is, I see cluster name 0____ with representation [,,,,,,,,].  I see that for most of the clusters.  The advice I get from Google Gemini is to call topic_model.fit(all_documents) on all of my documents, which is currently a minuscule 86 GB compressed on disk, way too much for RAM.  How can I fill in representations for these clusters?
